# How can I use LIMIT on specific nodes in a path in CYPHER?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say I have this query:

[image]

How can I use LIMIT on different layers of this path? It seems to only affect the last node in a path.

What if I wanted say 1 Year, 3 Months, and then 5 days for each of the months?

How about with a conditional on corresponding months? i.e. if M=2, get D=[1,2,3,4,5], if M=3, D=[11,12,13,14,15])?

Something like this:

[image]

As of now I have been manually editing these diagrams by expanding, deleting, expanind, etc. It is quite tedious, so I'm hoping there is a way to do this in the query.

I've tried a few things like mulitple returns with separate limits, unions, but I can't seem to make anything work.

I would like to do this in the browser. I believe that means it must be a single command.

I've been trying things like:

```
MATCH (t:TimeTreeRoot)-[c1:CHILD]-(y:Year) 
WITH t, c1, y LIMIT 1 
MATCH (t)-[c1]-(y)-[c2:CHILD]-(m:Month) 
WITH t, c1, y, c2, m LIMIT 3 
MATCH (m)-[c3:CHILD]-(d:Day) 
WITH t, c1, y, c2, m, c3, d 
MATCH p=(t)-[c1]-(y)-[c2]-(m)-[c2]-(d) 
RETURN p LIMIT N
```

But the behaviour is inconsistent. It seems as though a preceding LIMIT is negated by a following one.

Comment: Can you please export this graph as a CSV (using the Neo4j web UI) and share (e.g. with a GitHub Gist) so that we can experiment with it?

Comment: I just created the CSV, but when I manually modified it, the export results did not change. You just want the csv from the 1st image right? [Here](https://gist.github.com/spanishgum/132e08de11db0e00df1ebd74da0cac7f) it is. Let me know if you want more than that. I've got a huge graph so I can't give all but I will provide if you'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do all this in a single match and capture it as a path. At this time LIMIT applies to the entire result set. If Neo4j adds subqueries in the future, then you can use it there in the way you intend.

You can get a similar result set of nodes in a different way though, by collecting nodes and getting the relevant slice, and if you want to, unwind the collection into rows afterward.

```
MATCH (t:TimeTreeRoot)-[:CHILD]->(y:Year)-[:CHILD]->(m:Month)
WITH t, y, m LIMIT 3
MATCH (m)-[:CHILD]->(d:Day)
WITH t, y, m, COLLECT(d)[0..5] as days
UNWIND days as d
RETURN t, y, m, d
```

Alternately, since you're working with TimeTree and have the value properties to work with, you could use those to select the exact days you want (provided they have been created).

```
MATCH (t:TimeTreeRoot)-[:CHILD]->(y:Year)-[:CHILD]->(m:Month)
WITH t, y, m LIMIT 3
MATCH (m)-[:CHILD]->(d:Day)
WHERE d.value in RANGE(1,5)
RETURN t, y, m, d
```

You can add to your WHERE clause to get different days per month.

```
MATCH (t:TimeTreeRoot)-[:CHILD]->(y:Year)-[:CHILD]->(m:Month)
WITH t, y, m LIMIT 3
MATCH (m)-[:CHILD]->(d:Day)
WHERE (m.value = 3 AND d.value in RANGE(11,15)) OR (m.value <> 3 AND d.value in RANGE(1,5))
RETURN t, y, m, d
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! This also helped me realize how the UNWIND function works. Thank you! As a side note: You forgot `t, y, m` in your last `WITH` statement on the first code block.

Comment: Ah, thanks for catching that! I fixed the query. Glad to help!